# How do I initialize a variable instance which is an object properly?

Tags: objective-c

I am an Objective C newbie and I'm sure this is an easy question but I can't figure this out:
I have a class which declares an instance variable called myDeck, which is part of a custom class I created called Deck. Right now I have this in my code:

In the @interface:

```
Deck *myDeck;
```

In my init method:

```
Deck *ourDeck = [[Deck alloc]init];
myDeck = ourDeck;
```

So this seems to create the myDeck just fine, and I can stick values in it and run it's methods for a while, but I'm running into a spot where it ceases to exist and I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to use it.

I have tried adding

```
[myDeck retain];
```

to no avail, it still fails in the same spots. I don't really know how I should be alloc and initting this, I have a feeling I am missing something, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you're doing there seems right; except I think you might have a typo in your first example - the instance variable is called `myDeck`, not `deck`, right?  If your object is disappearing it's because you called `release` or `autorelease` too many times.  Memory management in Cocoa is pretty straightforward.  Go check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for all the information you could ever want.

Comment: Oops, yes, that was a typo (in my code the var is named deck and I changed it for clarity in this post).

I guess you're right, something must be releasing it too much, I can't figure out what though, I don't call retain or autorelease myself at all, I guess something going on in my program is releasing it. I tried pasting in a couple of dozen [myDeck retain] statements right after the code I posted but that doesn't help heh. I guess it's something that'll seem obvious when I find it.

Comment: @Cocorico, are you sure you're keeping good pointers to the object?  You can get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` by trying to access bad pointers, too.

Comment: I don't know, that is probably my problem I am thinking. I don't 100% understand what a good or bad pointer is. Like, in my code, when I use the myDeck object, I am basically just doing stuff like this:

    [myDeck shuffleDeck];
    ...
    [myDeck printOutCards];

If that makes any sense. It's interesting that the printOutCards command I just typed there works in the init method and another method, but not in the method where I am getting errors.

Comment: Also, one other thing I wonder: the "myDeck = ourDeck" command I know does not COPY ourDeck into myDeck, I believe it simply makes myDeck a umm.. pointer to ourDeck (if I say that right?). I wonder if that is causing trouble.

Comment: Sorry to keep writing but I noticed that my log window keeps talking about GDB mode the last hour or so, which I have not noticed it talking about before. Did I maybe hit some key combo by accident to put me in some different than normal debug mode? I have googled and can't figure out offhand if this is different from just having "debug" as my active build configuration which I think I have had until now. (I just switched it to "release" and the program now works although there is clearly some underlying memory issues I guess right since it fails in debug mode?)